# Hangfire BackgroundJob.Enqueue and method serialization

Tags: c#, hangfire

With hangfire we can do something like:

```
public MyClass
{
    public void RunJob()
    {
        SomeClass x = new SomeClass();
        x.SomeProperty = "Test";
        Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => x.SomeMethod());
    }
}
```

Imagine that `SomeMethod` is not static, and depends upon the value of SomeClass.SomeProperty. If `SomeMethod` is not static, how can this work? Object `x` will go out of scope two lines later. Does Hangfire increase the reference count to object `x` and the garbage collector doesn't clean up the object until Hangfire is done with it?

Further, imagine if `SomeClass` implements IDisposable and `SomeMethod` depends upon resources cleaned up by Dispose:

```
public MyClass
{
    public void RunJob()
    {
        using (SomeClass x = new SomeClass())
        {
            x.SomeProperty = "Test";
            Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => x.SomeMethod());
        }
    }
}
```

In this case x.Dispose would likely be called before the job is run. Does this cause a bug?

In testing I can see that private member SomeClass._disposed is set to true following the using statement, but when Hangfire calls `SomeMethod` seconds later, SomeClass._disposed is set to false! How does this black magic happen!?

**Observations**

I modified the class to include:

```
public MyClass
{
    public static int LastId = 0;
    private static int Id = 0;

    public MyClass()
    {
        Id = ++LastId;
    }

    public void RunJob()
    {
        using (SomeClass x = new SomeClass())
        {
            x.SomeProperty = "Test";
            Hangfire.BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => x.SomeMethod());
        }
    }
}
```

... using this I can observe that the `Id` of the class used by Hangfire is not the same instance used in my first example. So I assume Enqueue makes a copy of object x, or maybe the () => operator does.

Comment: Since it's working,  there's only one possible explanation that I can see: Hangfire serialises the arguments (including `x` in this case) and stores it in the database. When it's time to run the task, it's serialised again, and a new instance created. [This](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-arguments.html) page in the documentation says that this is how it's done for arguments - so I guess `x` qualifies as an argument (to Hangfire at least)

Comment: I have not read the source code - but private members are possible to get at using reflection. So that's at least one possible solution they've used. You'd have to read through the [source code](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire) to find out for certain.

Comment: @fredrik Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In testing I can see that private member SomeClass._disposed is set to
>   true following the using statement, but when Hangfire calls SomeMethod
>   seconds later, SomeClass._disposed is set to false! How does this
>   black magic happen!?

Because both `x` are not the same objects. The one ran by hangfire is the result of the deserialization of the one ran by the main program which has been serialized upon enqueing.

> In this case x.Dispose would likely be called before the job is run.
>   Does this cause a bug?

This may cause a bug. For example, if running hangfire in the same appdomain as the main program and if disposing `x` also disposes a shared resource which would be used by the `x` deserialized by hangfire. Disposing objects which are part of the enqueing action seems like a code smell to me, because these objects are meant to be serializable.

Take a look at the `Enqueue` method. You will notice that it takes an `Expression<Action>` as parameter (and not just an `Action`).
This expression will get serialized as well as all its parameters and constants and be deserialized upon dequeueing by Hangfire.